# Intellij IDEA 13 - Artifact build process with latest JS files (Via grunt build)

Tags: shell, build, intellij-idea, gruntjs

Is it possible in Intellij (13) to execute `grunt build` (shell command) as part of the artifact build process so that the artifact to be deploy contains the up to date JS/CSS/HTML files? I see `'Run Ant target'`that looks like it would execute a shell command but i'm not using ant (nor do I want to)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that IntelliJ is using Ant as an adapter to all other tools, because you can run pretty much anything with it.

Just add the following build.xml to your project.

```
<project name="grunt" default="build">
    <target name="build">
        <exec executable="grunt">
            <arg value="build"/>          
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: thanks but Was hoping not to do add an ant file - so be it if there is no other option...

Comment: @Ian I don't see any other option as of now, but if I find anything, I will update the answer. You can also email to JetBrains support, they will give you the ultimate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

*I stumbled upon this question when I was interested in exactly the same. I am using IntelliJ Idea for more than a decade. Now, when I started to work with Angular, NodeJS/NPM and build by Grunt, I really wanted to be able to continue building and launching my development artifacts from the IDE seamlessly, without any manual steps to execute Grunt/browserify even if it is "just" another click on a button before you build. So...*

One solution to trigger a Grunt task execution in IntelliJ Idea as a part of the artifact build process, would be to add `exec-maven-plugin` and bind it to an execution phase e.g. `prepare-package`, most likely in some separate profile. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>grunt</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>grunt${script.extension}</executable>
                <workingDirectory>angular-app</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--no-color</argument>
                    <argument>${grunt.task}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now in the "Maven Projects" tool window you can right-click the appropriate lifecycle phase in the list and mark as "Execute before rebuild".

**This should do the job and satisfy your requirement not to use Ant.**

**But** in my case (though I don't use Ant as a build system for a long time now, nor I like Ant too much), I decided to take the approach proposed by @kukido in his answer. This way I didn't modify Maven to suit IDE which I consider to be conceptually incorrect as the build system (Maven in my case) should not be influenced by anything imposed by IDE. I really think that such a great tool as IntelliJ Idea can take one step further and provide possibility to run more arbitrary commands/goals on "Pre-precess" of preparing an artifact in IDE. For now I will use the Ant as a thin adapter here and keep my POM clean.